# Possivel Plugin para ver se é responsive ou não

Tags: layout-responsivo

Tenho uma duvida relativamente simples, estou a procura de algum `plugin` para o `chrome`, mas ainda não consegui encontrar exatamente o que queria, que basicamente é para ver se o nosso `website` está `responsive` em todos os ecrãs possíveis.

Sei que existe o `inspect element` e redimensionar a página, mas queria algo mais fácil de lidar, pois nem sempre as dimensões são iguais quando estas são redimensionadas.

Comment: No Chrome tem a opção [`Toggle Device Mode`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) que permite simular diferentes dimensões de ecrã (tem vários tipos de dispositivos), assim como analisar as `media queries` feitas e ainda simular redes mais lentas (*throttling*). Para aceder a esta opção abra as ferramentas de *developer* (Ctrl + Shift + I).

Comment: Sim, mas não consigo fazer as media queries, e aí está o meu problema. Daí optar por um plugin, talvez será mais fácil de ver o que está bem feito ou não, nem que me abra +4 janelas por aí. Obrigado @jsantos1991 pelo edit

Comment: Para ver as `media queries` tem um [botao](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#media-queries) que lhe permite ver quais foram as `media queries` feitas e a que dimensões.

Comment: Sim, mobile device! Eu já testei, mas não resulta o inspect element, eu altero até a cor e não muda. Pode ser bem capaz que seja o meu chrome que esteja com problemas derivado á ultima actualização...

Comment: Experimenta o [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/pt-br/developer/mobile-emulator). Com ele você cria uma instância do Opera pré-configurada com vários aspectos referentes à responsividade. Tem uns *presets* pra você configurar com base nas especificações de um smartphone/tablet em particular ou criar seu próprio a partir de um modelo base.

Comment: Atenção, procuro para o Chrome. Ainda não estou na fase de testes multi-browser! Mas obrigado pelo conselho.

Comment: Você disse que queria algo fácil, esse emulador simula o dispositivo e não o navegador. *It's something...*

Comment: Sim, mas a ideia é ser do navegador...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O plugin [Responsive Web Design Tester](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-web-design-tes/objclahbaimlfnbjdeobicmmlnbhamkg) parece ser o que você busca.

Comment: Vou tentar esse plugin, tenho andado a ver os plugins, e penso que este parece o ideal. Obrigado